# *ngif to not display home link on home page

Tags: angular

In my nav component I want the home link to not display when on the home page. This code is not working:

```
 <button 
     mat-button 
     *ngIf="path !== '/home' && path !== '/' "
     routerLink="/home">
     <span>Home</span>
 </button>
```

Comment: What is `path`? Can you share your javascript code as well where you assign that?

Comment: It was path. I changed it to routerlink and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a function on component that returns a boolean value if the path is right:

```
private isHomePage(): boolean {
    return window.location.href.includes("home"); // Or any equasions you like
}
```

than in your html just:

```
<button mat-button *ngIf="!isHomePage()" routerLink="/home"> <span>Home</span> </button>
```

tough this is one way to do it, you can implelment the router service and check the url or route from there but the way is preety similiar

Comment: The button will still be displayed since the if condition is inside the button, the button will still be visible, and therefore does not solve the problem. The button will be read regardless of the if condition output.

Comment: This is nonsense!
That is the exact job of the ngIf to control on that same element you set it on and not only its content...
you got a bit confused i believe

Comment: Hmm, I don't know for sure if that is the nature of the `*ngIf`, but it seemed to me that the button would still be rendered whether or not the if would output true or false. I thought that the text might disappear at the very least, but the actual element will be there. I'm not too sure, but it seemed logical to me.

Comment: window.location.href.includes is not a good way , instead use the ActiveRoute and route services of angular to  fetch current path

Comment: Thx Manpreet, as i mentioned in the bottom of my answer that this is just the simplest way to show the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import **@angular/router** on component

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

and declare it in **constructor**

```js
private router: Router
```

and create a function

```js
hasRoute(route: string) {
  return this.router.url == route;
}
```

After that, in the HTML file, just need to add this into your element

```js
*ngIf="!hasRoute('/')"
```